# Notation in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation

What does $(A\mid b)$ denote in Linear Algebra? Specifically in the context of the following question:

"If $(A\mid b)$ is in reduced row echelon form, prove that A is also in reduced row echelon form."

Comment: Given two matrices $A_{m\times n},B_{m\times p}$, the $m\times (n+p)$ matrix whose $(i,j)$ entry is $$\begin{cases} (A)_{(i,j)}, &\text{if }j\leq n\\ (B)_{(i, j-n)}, &\text{if }j\ge n+1\end{cases}$$ is called the [augmented matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_matrix) and is denoted by $\left(A\mid B\right)$.

Comment: To put the comment of Git Gud into words: You get the augmented matrix if you write the matrix $A$ as a table and add the vector $b$ as an extra column to the right.